# PyQt4 : Linking buttons to functions

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, pyqt, pyqt4

So I have this GUI that has 2 empty text spots to fill and a "Run" button

I want to make it that the 2 empty text spots go to values in the program and the run button will run the python "Main" program  ..

How can i do that ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a look at the documentation for PyQt signals and slots. Normally, when you install PyQt you also install some great examples. Walk through the code and it will teach you a lot (search your filesystem for "qtdemo" or *standarddialogs.py*).

- [New-style signals and slots](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/new_style_signals_slots.html)
- [Old-style signals and slots](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/old_style_signals_slots.html)

Here's a snippet from *standarddialogs.py*:

```
self.saveFileNameButton = QPushButton("QFileDialog.get&SaveFileName()")
...
self.saveFileNameButton.clicked.connect(self.setSaveFileName)
...
def setSaveFileName(self):
```

Comment: ive used the designer to make the ui ... now what do i need to do?
i didnt code the gui

Comment: You will learn a lot more by building the gui by hand. Please see the answer on your duplicate question, the person who answered that question has left an excellent walkthrough of how to build the gui. As I've noted in my answer, the key part for the command is the clicked.connect.